# How to set scrolling of resized Image inside ScrollViewer C# WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, image, scrollbar, scrollviewer

I've got a ScrollViewer with an Image inside. 
Image can be resized with usage of Image.RenderTransform.ScaleTransform by pressing buttons.

What I need is correct size of scrollbars, because, when Image is Zoomed, the scrollbars react change of size of Image, BUT, it's not enough to scroll image fully and to view total image, so part of image disappears, when image is Zoomed. Please let me know, what horrible mistakes I did this time, because I tried many StackOverflow advices, but still, I haven't understood the logic of how ScrollViewer should operate. Thanks in advance.

[Right edge of image is not shown](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S8f9A.png)

Here is small part of my XAML settings.

```xml
       <Grid>
            <ScrollViewer x:Name="svImageViewer" Margin="100,50,100,100" Width="768" Height="800"  VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"   HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"  Visibility="Hidden" Grid.Row="0">
                <Image x:Name="imgViewer"  VerticalAlignment="Center"  HorizontalAlignment="Center" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" MouseWheel="imgViewer_MouseWheel">
                        <Image.RenderTransform>
                            <TransformGroup>
                                <ScaleTransform x:Name="ScaleTransform" CenterX="0.5" CenterY="0.5" ScaleX="{Binding ScaleX}" ScaleY="{Binding ScaleY}"/>
                                <TranslateTransform x:Name="TranslateTransform"/>
                            </TransformGroup>
                        </Image.RenderTransform>
                    </Image>
            </ScrollViewer>
        </Grid>
```

Here is how image resizing is done.

```cs
private void btnZoom_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var transformGroup = (TransformGroup)imgViewer.RenderTransform;
    var st = (ScaleTransform)transformGroup.Children[0];
    if ((st.ScaleX + 0.2) > 3 || (st.ScaleY + 0.2) > 3)
        return;
    st.ScaleX += 0.2;
    st.ScaleY += 0.2;
    imgViewer.LayoutTransform = st;
}
private void btnZoomOut_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var transformGroup = (TransformGroup)imgViewer.RenderTransform;
    var st = (ScaleTransform)transformGroup.Children[0];
    if ((st.ScaleX - 0.2) < 0.8 || (st.ScaleY - 0.2) < 0.8)
        return;
    st.ScaleX += -0.2;
    st.ScaleY += -0.2;
    imgViewer.LayoutTransform = st;
}
```

Comment: Do not set the Image's RenderTransform and LayoutTransform at the same time. LayoutTransform only should work and keep the ScrollViewer in sync.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Clemens' comment, I managed to change my code and now it works for me. Please forgive me, if this solution is primitive and incorrect, maybe it will help someone.

```
<Grid>
    <ScrollViewer x:Name="svImageViewer" Margin="100,100,100,100" Width="{Binding svImageViewerWidth}" Height="{Binding svImageViewerHeight}"  VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"   HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"  Visibility="Hidden" Grid.Row="0">
        <Image x:Name="imgViewer"  VerticalAlignment="Center"  HorizontalAlignment="Center"  MouseWheel="imgViewer_MouseWheel">
                <Image.LayoutTransform>
                    <ScaleTransform x:Name="ScaleTransform" CenterX="0.5" CenterY="0.5" ScaleX="{Binding ScaleX}" ScaleY="{Binding ScaleY}"/>
                </Image.LayoutTransform>
            </Image>
    </ScrollViewer>
</Grid>
```

Probably, you will need reset image position after zooming, I added my solution for this.

```cs
private void btnZoom_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var st = (ScaleTransform)imgViewer.LayoutTransform;
    if ((st.ScaleX + 0.2) > 3 || (st.ScaleY + 0.2) > 3)
        return;
    st.ScaleX += 0.2;
    st.ScaleY += 0.2;
    imgViewer.LayoutTransform = st;
}
private void btnZoomOut_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var st = (ScaleTransform)imgViewer.LayoutTransform;
    if ((st.ScaleX - 0.2) < 0.8 || (st.ScaleY - 0.2) < 0.8)
        return;
    st.ScaleX += -0.2;
    st.ScaleY += -0.2;
    imgViewer.LayoutTransform = st;
}
public void ResetImagePosition()
        {
            var st = (ScaleTransform)imgViewer.LayoutTransform;
            st.ScaleX = 1;
            st.ScaleY = 1;
            imgViewer.LayoutTransform = st;
            svImageViewer.ScrollToHome();
        }
public void SetControlSizes()
        {
            gridPreviewWidth = Window.ActualWidth - 30;
            svImageViewerHeight = Window.ActualHeight-200;
            svImageViewerWidth = Window.ActualWidth-100 ;
        }
```